# Get the type of a script in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got this code:

```cs
public void UpgradeShootSpeed(String shooter, int level) {
    /*Something*/ shooter_script = GameObject.Find(shooter).GetComponent(shooter);
    shooter_script.shoot_speed = level;
}
```

I want to be able to upgrade the shoot speed of any shooter by passing its name (e. g. "BigShooter"). The Script should get the GameObject named after the shooter and get the equally named Script attached to the GameObject. Then I'll set the shoot speed in that script. But the type of the Script is different for each script. How can I get the type of the Script, or solve the problem another way?

Comment: Why are you passing the component type in as a string? Using the `GetComponent<T>` method would be way preferable

Comment: [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) .. it won't help you much with your use case though ;)

Comment: @UnholySheep [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) can also take a `Type` or `string` but  @OP either way you would need to know what to cast it to in order to be able to use a specific method anyway .... So I think it would help a lot if you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understand you correctly. You have multiple subclasses of the Component class and all of your subclasses have a field named `shoot_speed`.

Solution: [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) - You need a middle [abstract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) class which have the `shoot_speed` field, then you can get this component with the `GetComponent<T>` method.

Example:

```
public abstract class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int shoot_speed;
}

public class Pistol : Weapon { }
public class MachineGun : Weapon { }
```

So the `UpgradeShootSpeed` method looks like:

```
public void UpgradeShootSpeed(String shooter, int level)
{
    Weapon shooter_script = GameObject.Find(shooter).GetComponent<Weapon>();
    shooter_script.shoot_speed = level;
}
```